# why arent my links white and without the line under?

Tags: javascript, html, css, nav

im trying to create a disney plus clone and im just starting out. In the navbar the links should be white and without the underline i have the no text decoration but it still shows up i dont understand.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    width: 100%;
    background: #0c111b;
    position: relative;
    font-family: roboto, sans-serif;
}

.navbar{
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0 4%;
    background: #0c111b;
    z-index: 9;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.brand-logo{
    height: 70px;
}

.nav-links{
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-items{
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 20px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0,9;
}

.right-container{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.search-box{
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
    background: transparent;
    outline: none;
    height: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    width: 250px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    transition: .5s;
}

.search-box:focus{
    width: 400px;
    border-color: #1f80e0;
}

.sub-btn{
    background: #1f80e0;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0 10px;
}

.login-link{
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.9;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <img src="images/logo.png" class="brand-logo" alt="">
        <ul class="nav-links">
            <li class="nav-items"><a href="#">TV</a></li>
            <li class="nav-items"><a href="#">movies</a></li>
            <li class="nav-items"><a href="#">sports</a></li>
            <li class="nav-items"><a href="#">premium</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="right-container">
            <input type="text" class="search-box" placeholder="search">
            <button class="sub-btn">Subscribe</button>
            <a href="#" class="login-link">login</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Target `.nav-items a` or put the class on the `<a>`. Also `opacity: 0,9` should be `0.9`

Answer (score 4):

Default browser styles for the `<a>` element include values for properties:

- `color`
- `text-decoration`

and these default values will *always* apply unless you **explicitly** override them:

```
.nav-items {
  margin-left: 20px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.nav-items a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Browsers are applying embedded CSS.
by default, links are blue (purple then visited) and underlined, this is why you have these styles.

You can check the option to see the browser styles to verify this.
[image]

In every project you will always have to override default CSS styles, unless you use CSS frameworks, such as bootstrap, etc

Answer (score 0):

Use `text-decoration:none;`for your `nav-items a` element in your css.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    width: 100%;
    background: #0c111b;
    position: relative;
    font-family: roboto, sans-serif;
}

.navbar{
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0 4%;
    background: #0c111b;
    z-index: 9;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.brand-logo{
    height: 70px;
}

.nav-links{
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-items{
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 20px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0,9;
}

.right-container{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.search-box{
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
    background: transparent;
    outline: none;
    height: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    width: 250px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    transition: .5s;
}

.search-box:focus{
    width: 400px;
    border-color: #1f80e0;
}

.sub-btn{
    background: #1f80e0;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0 10px;
}

.login-link{
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.9;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-items a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <img src="images/logo.png" class="brand-logo" alt="">
        <ul class="nav-links">
            <li class="nav-items"><a href="#">TV</a></li>
            <li class="nav-items"><a href="#">movies</a></li>
            <li class="nav-items"><a href="#">sports</a></li>
            <li class="nav-items"><a href="#">premium</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="right-container">
            <input type="text" class="search-box" placeholder="search">
            <button class="sub-btn">Subscribe</button>
            <a href="#" class="login-link">login</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have targeted wrong css just add anchor tag to .nav-items class.Bydefault it has blue color and text-decoration-underline property so remove the default behavior by adding your css.

```
      .nav-items a {
              text-decoration: none;
              color: #fff;
           }
```